# Office 365 IP 22013Error This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

There seems to be something seriously missing in Office 365 publish web forms as content type, then add content type to library and then try to open a web enabled 2017 form and get the error Delete repeated word
"This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath."

All other settings are correct, in advance we indicate open as web form, we have used this same method with no problem in SP 2010 on our network.

We are using MS browsers, but every single form we publish after saving as web form whether published to a library or content type then added as content type to another library is not working and giving error about not opening in web.  This includes absolutely blank forms saved as 2013 web forms then published as content type.  I've had the privilege or working with technology since 2004 but here on the public Office 365 with SharePoint InfoPath refuses to open as a web form.  I'm on Windows 10, using IE edge, IE 11 and latest chrome and get the same issue.

No problem like this on our network 2010 but we would like to get up to date.

I've red through numerous 'answers' but doubt any are actually able to open in the web.  We haven't been successful at all.

Please somebody who know clearly how to resolve this issue or if this issue will never be resolved make the answer clear so we don't have to abandon using InfoPath in Office 365 without adequate replacement.

Comment: Open a case with Microsoft support in your tenant admin center.

Comment: thanks.  how?  who is the land lord?

Comment: https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx, if you can't you'll need to have one of your global administrators submit a ticket for you.

Comment: well creating a ticket led me to 'On the SharePoint admin center page, click InfoPath.
In the User Browser-enabled Form Templates section, specify how you want user form templates to be processed by InfoPath Forms Services by completing the following steps'  but it seems when you create office 365 account you are not the server admin.  I mean that's what the cloud I thought is about.  so how do I go to the admin settings as they recommended to be certain this allow forms to open in browser setting is enabled?

Comment: I have added myself as a site Collection administrators SharePoint group but see no way into what they refer to as the 'SharePoint admin center page" in order to configure to allow users to publish web based InfoPath forms which frankly should be turned on/enabled by default.

Comment: there are no more SharePoint administrators on the cloud.  My understanding the black hats who manage the cloud service are the SharePoint site administrators.  That's why we can't access the back end features.  It's not clear who to contact when using office 365 via Microsoft who to contact.  I opened a 'ticket' so maybe eventually someone will notice to enable the feature

Comment: The Sharepoint admin center is tenant-admin.sharepoint.com where you can see and manage things related to SharePoint, this is your SharePoint central admin. Errors and bugs that you can't fix should be reported to Microsoft, https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx.